# русские символы c char

Tags: c++

С помощью curl читаю xml документ с кодировкой windows 1251. Я установил setlocale: `setlocale( LC_ALL, ".1251" );`. Теперь мне нужно провести поиск по считанному, но char отказывается принимать
строку для поиска с русскими символами. При этом считанный текст выводится в консоль корректно, но собственный текст заменяется иероглифами.(платформа: windows, компилятор: mingw)

код:

```
char str[10]="Аыв";
cout<<endl<<str<<endl<<parse.Ptext<<endl;
```

вывод:

```
Р№С┼С?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><ValCurs Date="20.10.2021" name="Foreign Currency Market"><Valute ID="R01010"><NumCode>036</NumCode><CharCode>AUD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Австралийский доллар</Name><Value>52,9843</Value>
```

Comment: прям так и говорит char? не хочу твою строку? ( с другой стороны - char - это один символ, а строка - это массив). показывайте хоть кусок кода

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); пробовали?

Comment: результат тот же

Comment: и как я подозреваю вот это вот char str[10]="Аыв";  написано в исходнике в юникоде

Comment: спасибо, даже не думал о кодировке файла